# Error when installing SugarCRM 6.5.22 on centos 6.6

Tags: php, apache, centos, crm, sugarcrm

i installing SugarCRM 6.5.22 but meet this error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server
>   on 'crm.vieter.vn' (111) in
>   /storage/www/crm.vieter.vn/include/database/MysqliManager.php on line
>   278
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in /storage/www/crm.vieter.vn/include/database/MysqliManager.php
>   on line 307
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in /storage/www/crm.vieter.vn/include/database/MysqliManager.php
>   on line 313
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   boolean given in
>   /storage/www/crm.vieter.vn/include/database/MysqliManager.php on line
>   254
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in /storage/www/crm.vieter.vn/include/database/MysqliManager.php
>   on line 132
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in /storage/www/crm.vieter.vn/include/database/MysqliManager.php
>   on line 132 Please fix the following errors before proceeding:
>
> The provided database host, username, and/or password is invalid, and
>   a connection to the database could not be established. Please enter a
>   valid host, username and password Unable to check database version.
>   * Required field
>
> My info server: Centos 6.6, PHP 5.4.40, Apache 2.2.50

Anyone can help me

Thanks,
Toan

Comment: hi check config.php and check all db configurations are correct, and make sure that your mysqld service is running.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of few problems:
1. do you have mysqld running?
2. are you using the right host, username, password, database name?

Comment: i running mysqld, and using the right host, username, password, database name but still be this error